# JQuery Sliding Up each element that have an id that start with "F" with a delay

Tags: jquery, selector, delay, each

I have a couple of `<div>` that I wish to animate using JQuery. I need to display the first `<div>` for 7 sec. then slide it down and display the next `<div>` for 7 sec.

Here is the HTML code that countains my `<div>`:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<div id='F1' class='Nouvelles' style='background- image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/google_chrome.png); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
<div id='E2' class='Nouvelles' style='background-image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/images.jpeg); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
<div id='F3' class='Nouvelles' style='background-image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2>test 2 FR</h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

To accomplish this I tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready
        (function(){
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:"handlingPub.php",
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"text",
                contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                success:function(code_html, status)//code_html contains all the `<div>`
                            {
                                $("#divPub").append(code_html);
                                $(".Nouvelles").css(
                                    {
                                        height:"90px",
                                        display:"none",
                                        padding:"0px",
                                        margin:"10px",
                                        overflow:"hidden",
                                        border:"solid white 2px"
                                    });
                                $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]:lt(1)').css("display", "block");
                                $(".Nouvelles h2").css({padding:"0px", margin:"0px"});
                            } 
            });


            function()
            {
                $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).slideUp().delay(7000);
                        if($(this).next() != null)
                        {
                            $(this).next().slideDown();
                        }
                    });

            }
        });
```

Now here is the problem:
The first `<div>` is displayig correctly.
But I cant get into `$('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').each(function(){//I cant get here});`
and I dont know why. could some one point where I made a mistake?

OH! and btw I need only the `<div>` that have an `id` that start with `'F'`
So only F1 and F3 not E2.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').each` call is being made inside a function, which you do not appear to be calling. In this case, you need to just do what you want to do instead of making a function that does it. Get rid of the `function() {` and `}` around the `each` call and see if that helps.

Comment: I followed your advise but I end Up naming the function and calling it into my ajax success function.